# Ionic Framework and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Let me preface these questions with the statement, "I'm not a web developer." Most of my work has been done in Python for data analytics.

Cutting right to it, I'm in a scenario where I'm learning web technologies such as HTML/CSS, JS, Ionic, and AngularJS in order to debug a pretty horrendous mobile app written by previous developers.

The app was built in the Ionic framework using Cordova plugins and AngularJS (yes, not the new Angular 6-7).

My questions are:

1. I have the newest version of Ionic installed on my computer that supports Angular 6-7. Will I have to roll it back to a previous version for it to support AngularJS?
2. Can my app encounter some serious problems in the next year (or less) if it is not rewritten using the new Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should not need to downgrade your version of Ionic, but will need to install the @ionic/v1-toolkit package.

2) This is more a subjective question. It is my understanding that v1 will remain stable for at least the near future. However, it is unlikely to have any more active development. You might encounter the usual issues with an older ecosystem, e.g. deprecated dependancies, out of date architecture patterns, lack of learning resources.

I have upgraded a few apps from v1 to v3/v4 at this point, and I VASTLY prefer the modern angular style, architecture, and functionality. So there is that. Typescript is very useful as well. The app will eventually need to be upgraded, and the upgrade from 1 to 2 is a total rewrite as Maheshivirus states. The more work you do on the Ionic 1 app, the more difficult the upgrade will be. Being ignorant of your circumstances, it might be worth considering upgrading first to limit development of technical debt and to better future proof your app.

The good news is they use the same cordova, so native functionality is very unlikely to be affected. Newer version of Ionic are faster, support lazy loading, have better components aesthetically, and work better as PWAs. If any of those aspects are of interest to you, that could sway your decision. See [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-long-will-ionic-1-be-supported/106776) and [this one](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v1-support-long-term-support-support-subscriptions/121681) for a bit more info. Second link indicates that no active work is being done on version 1 anymore.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - If you want to run Ionic 1 app then you should downgrade your installed ionic version to ionic 1.
    -Ionic has updating day by day its better to update your ionic 1 projects to ionic 2+ because Ionic 2 is completely different from Ionic 1,as the language for framework has changed.Its no more angular 1,it's angular 2+ , TYPESCRIPT.
    -At a high level, Ionic 2+ is a complete rewrite of the Ionic 1 project with Angular >= 2.x.
```